# alertbuilder, title not shown

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an alertbuilder with a title and image:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);                   
builder.setTitle(R.string.pull);
builder.setIcon(R.drawable.tira_cable);
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.accept, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
      //actions
   }
   });
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

I checked the problem is not in the title, is in the image, because if I comment the setIcon line it shows the title.

Comment: Where is this code called from? What's the value of R.string.pull? And a screenshot of the dialog will also be useful.

Comment: Hey setTitle directly `alert.setTitle("Yourtext");`

Comment: I tried, but it doesnt work

Comment: check my ans.. you got your solution ----> http://stackoverflow.com/a/15519577/1168654

Answer (score 1):

> Use this snippet to fix it!!

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                            .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.pull))
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setMessage("Quistion???")
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(
                                                DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {

                                        }

                                    })
                            .setNegativeButton("No",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(
                                                DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {

                                        }
                                    }).show();
```

Comment: This does not highlight what he did wrong, it merely shows him what he has already done.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setTitle(int).  this not an an answer, because setTitle can take a resourceID.

Comment: getResources().getString(R.string.pull)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use like :

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.pull));
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_search);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // actions
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
```

Yor Title ll Showing now...